# RandomForestClassifier was given input with invalid label column error in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to find Accuracy using 5-fold cross validation using Random Forest Classifier Model in SCALA. But i am getting the following error while running:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RandomForestClassifier was given input with invalid label column label, without the number of classes specified. See StringIndexer.

Getting the above error at line---> val cvModel = cv.fit(trainingData)

The code which i used for cross validation of data set using random forest is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.{ParamGridBuilder, CrossValidator}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

val data = sc.textFile("exprogram/dataset.txt")
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
val parts = line.split(',')
LabeledPoint(parts(41).toDouble, 
Vectors.dense(parts(0).split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
}


val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)

val trainingData = training.toDF()

val testData = test.toDF()

val nFolds: Int = 5
val NumTrees: Int = 5

val rf = new     
RandomForestClassifier()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setFeaturesCol("features")
      .setNumTrees(NumTrees)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(rf)) 

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
          .build()

val evaluator = new  MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
    .setLabelCol("label")
    .setPredictionCol("prediction")
    .setMetricName("precision") 

val cv = new CrossValidator()
   .setEstimator(pipeline)
   .setEvaluator(evaluator) 
   .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
   .setNumFolds(nFolds)

val cvModel = cv.fit(trainingData)

val results = cvModel.transform(testData)
.select("label","prediction").collect

val numCorrectPredictions = results.map(row => 
if (row.getDouble(0) == row.getDouble(1)) 1 else 0).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
val accuracy = 1.0D * numCorrectPredictions / results.size

println("Test set accuracy: %.3f".format(accuracy))
```

Can any one please explain what is the mistake in the above code.

Answer (score 9):

`RandomForestClassifier`, same as many other ML algorithms, require specific metadata to be set on the label column and labels values to be integral values from [0, 1, 2 ..., #classes) represented as doubles. Typically this is handled by an upstream `Transformers` like `StringIndexer`. Since you convert labels manually metadata fields are not set and classifier cannot confirm that these requirements are satisfied.

```
val df = Seq(
  (0.0, Vectors.dense(1, 0, 0, 0)),
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(0, 1, 0, 0)),
  (2.0, Vectors.dense(0, 0, 1, 0)),
  (2.0, Vectors.dense(0, 0, 0, 1))
).toDF("label", "features")

val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setNumTrees(5)

rf.setLabelCol("label").fit(df)
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RandomForestClassifier was given input ...
```

You can either re-encode label column using `StringIndexer`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("label_idx")
  .fit(df)

rf.setLabelCol("label_idx").fit(indexer.transform(df))
```

or [set required metadata manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35922214/1560062):

```
val meta = NominalAttribute
  .defaultAttr
  .withName("label")
  .withValues("0.0", "1.0", "2.0")
  .toMetadata

rf.setLabelCol("label_meta").fit(
  df.withColumn("label_meta", $"label".as("", meta))
)
```

**Note**:

Labels created using `StringIndexer` depend on the frequency not value:

```
indexer.labels
// Array[String] = Array(2.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

**PySpark**:

In Python metadata fields can be set directly on the schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, DoubleType

StructField(
    "label", DoubleType(), False,
    {"ml_attr": {
        "name": "label",
        "type": "nominal", 
        "vals": ["0.0", "1.0", "2.0"]
    }}
)
```