# How to attach metadata to a double column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, metadata, apache-spark-ml

I have a `double`-typed column in a dataframe that holds the class label for a Random Forest training set.
I would like to manually attach metadata to the column so that I don't have to pass the dataframe into a `StringIndexer` as suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517302/randomforestclassifier-was-given-input-with-invalid-label-column-error-in-apache).
The easiest method of doing this seems to be by using the `as` method of `Column`.
However, this method is not available in Python.

Is there an easy workaround?

If there is no easy workaround and the best approach is a Python port of `as`, then why is the method not ported in Python?
Is there a difficult technical reason and not simply because it conflicts with the `as` keyword in Python and that no one has volunteered to port it?

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/column.py) and found that the `alias` method in Python internally calls the `as` method in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import json
from pyspark.sql.column import Column

def add_meta(col, metadata):
    meta = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.types\
             .Metadata.fromJson(json.dumps(metadata))
    return Column(getattr(col._jc, "as")('', meta))

# sample invocation
df.withColumn('label', 
               add_meta(df.classification, 
                        {"ml_attr": {
                             "name": "label", 
                             "type": "nominal", 
                             "vals": ["0.0", "1.0"]
                                }
                        }))\
  .show()
```

This solution involves calling the `as(alias: String, metadata: Metadata)` Scala method in Python. It can be retrieved by `getattr(col._jc, "as")` where `col` is a dataframe column (`Column` object).

This returned function must then be called with two arguments. The first argument is just a string and the second argument is a `Metadata`. The object is created by calling `Metadata.fromJson()` which expects a JSON string as parameter. The method is retrieved via the `_jvm` attribute of the Spark context.

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.3+**

```py
df.withMetadata("col_name", meta_dict)
```

**Spark 2.2+**

```py
df.withColumn("col_name", df.col_name.alias("", metadata=meta_dict))
```

`meta_dict` can be a complex dictionary, as provided in the other answer:

```py
meta_dict = {
    "ml_attr": {
         "name": "label", 
         "type": "nominal", 
         "vals": ["0.0", "1.0"]
    }
}
```